# how can i make a tablelayout invisible and then visible in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, tablelayout

i have a winform that needs to print a chessboard, i have a table with some controls in it.

what i did was to set it invisible when the form loads

```
private void Chess_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PromotionTable.Visible =false;
}
```

and then make it visible once the function is triggered.

```
public void piecePromotionChange(Pieces[,] pieces, int rowEnd2, int columnEnd2, bool blackOrNot)
{
    PromotionTable.Visible = true;
}
```

but it still remains, invisible :(

Comment: @Fun Mun Pieng: I voted to approve your edit, although I personally think that SwDevMan81's original edit to split the function arguments over two lines was more readable. Side scrolling is no fun.

Comment: The simple explanation is that it actually gets visible but that there's something wrong with the content so it just isn't obvious.  Change the BackColor property to verify this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to invalidate/refresh that portion of the screen. Setting the Visible property does not trigger a redraw..

```
PromotionTable.Visible=true;
PromotionTable.Invalidate();
myForm.Refresh();
```

Comment: Awesome, i will check , the algorithm you provided me tonight and come back to you with an answer

Answer (score 1):

You probably ment to set its visibility to `false` on load

```
private void Chess_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   PromotionTable.Visible = false; // false here
}
```

If its not visible to begin with, you might need to check and make sure its added to the controls.

Comment: sorry , i mispelled, it shoudl be false